# Sorting data in ng-repeat angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sorting

I am trying to sort data using orderBy in angular js, but it is not sorting data.

can any one help me out ?

please check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1424/)

I am using following code

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
<div ng-repeat="person in data | orderBy:person.order">
        {{data.indexOf(person)}}  
        {{person.name}}
        {{person.order}}
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: can i know why downvote ? you can check problem in link of fiddle.

Comment: I don't think this should be downvoted.. Have my upvote.

Comment: @Billy thanks i solved out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small changes, remove person, and add quotes

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data | orderBy:'order'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
<div ng-repeat="person in data | orderBy:'order'">
        {{data.indexOf(person)}}  
        {{person.name}}
        {{person.order}}
    </div>    
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your parameter in single quotes as you are passing it to the filter function.  `'param'`, and also since you are already iterating the object, just the property name is sufficient.

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
<div ng-repeat="person in data | orderBy:'order'">
        {{data.indexOf(person)}}  
        {{person.name}}
        {{person.order}}
    </div>    
</div>
```